# Cannot Include <condition_variable> with clang 3.5

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

I have installed clang 3.5 on debian and just by including the  header I get the following compiler errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/chrono:540:6: error: no matching constructor for 
initialization of 'duration' (aka 'std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 1000000> >')
```

The complete error is here (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bnVuEmFg)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What if you `#include <chrono>` before including `<condition_variable>`?

Comment: I tried that and same error.

Comment: The error happens in chrono header which is included by condition_variable header.

Comment: OK, then update your question with the line in `<condition_variable>` causing the error, along with a description of the types involved. And post the entire error message, doesn't clang give a list of the constructors it tried to (unsuccessfully) match?

Answer (score 0):

According to @Marshall Clow my problem is fixed with gcc 4.7.3 and 4.8.

Comment: `-stdlib=libc++` probably would have avoided this.